# Python: inherit from the built-in list type VS filter, map built-in functions

Tags: python, subclass

I'm trying to build a class based on built-in list type:

```
class MyList(list):

    def __getslice__(self, i, j):
        return MyList(
            super(MyList, self).__getslice__(i, j)
        )

    def __add__(self,other):
        return MyList(
            super(MyList, self).__add__(other)
        )

    def __mul__(self,other):
        return MyList(
            super(MyList, self).__mul__(other)
        )

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        result = super(MyList, self).__getitem__(item)
        try:
            return MyList(result)
        except TypeError:
            return result
```

and I'm wondering if there's a way to make MyList class work with built-in functions like filter or map. By "work with" I mean to make filter and map return MyList class object instead of list type object.

```
>>> a = MyList([1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> type(a)
<class '__main__.MyList'>
>>> b = filter(lambda this: this > 2, a)
>>> type(b)
<type 'list'>
```

I'd like type(b) to return the same as type(a) returns.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you'll have to cast the output of `filter()` or `map()` back to `MyList`. These functions are documented to produce a `list`, (almost) always. They do so if you pass *other* types of sequences as well.

Quoting from the [`map()` documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map):

> The *iterable* arguments may be a sequence or any iterable object; the result is always a list.

In other words, `filter()` and `map()` don't care about the exact type of the sequences you pass in, that is not limited to your `MyList` type.

The exception is `filter()`, which special-cases for `tuple()` and `str()`; quoting the [`filter()` documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter):

> If iterable is a string or a tuple, the result also has that type; otherwise it is always a list.

This special handling is hard-coded and cannot be extended. In Python 3, this exception no longer applies; both `map()` and `filter()` return a *generator* there instead.

Comment: +1, but minor addition - I've decided to check and found, that for tuple and str filter will produce a tuple or str :) In all other cases it will produce list.
http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html - If sequence is a string or tuple, the result will be of the same type; otherwise, it is always a list

Comment: @RomanPekar: ick, I knew I should have verified the assertion there.

Comment: Thought so. Thanks for confirmation :)

Answer (score 0):

You "could" (not saying you should) do the following

```
_filter = filter
def filter(a,b):
    return MyList(filter(a,b))
```

Comment: Yes, but it's not the direction I'd like to go. Since it can't be implemented directly in MyList I'll rather use a simple casting, as I already did. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

based on Jakob Bowyer answer, you could do this:

```
__filter = filter
def filter(a, b):
    if isinstance(b, MyList):
        return MyList(__filter(a, b))
    else:
        return __filter(a ,b)

>>> a = MyList([1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> b = filter(lambda this: this > 2, a)
>>> type(b)
<class '__main__.MyList'>
```